# T4 Toolbox Linq2Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, t4, t4-toolbox

I'm trying to use t4toolbox to generate the linq2sql classes for a project.  There is already a lot of code written against the default dbml generated code.

In the LinqToSqlEntityClassTemplate.tt file it has

```
/// <para>
/// While MSLinqToSQLGenerator generates field names as property name with an
/// underscore prefix, this method simply converts the property name to camelCase.
/// This is done for consistency with the StyleCop rule SA1306: Variable names
/// must start with a lower-case letter.
/// </para>
```

Is there any way to make it generate the files in the default manner (Visual Studio way) instead of camelCasing and not having underscores?

The code generated by t4toolbox causes 400+ errors because of the field name differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy the T4 Linq2Sql template that you want to modify in you project. You just have to make the same hierarchy as in T4Toolbox: at the root of your project, add a folder `T4Toolbox/LinqToSql` and copy the template `LinqToSqlEntityClassTemplate.tt` from your T4Toolbox install into your project. You just have to edit the `FieldName` methods to change the naming of fields.

[image: project view in Visual Studio]

Comment: In the LinqToSqlEntityClassTemplate.tt I see two FieldName definitions.  Both of them return FieldName(prop).  Where is that FieldName() method that's transforming the property names?

Comment: It's in the base `T4Toolbox.dll` and provide camelCasing. You'll have to change both `FieldName(Column)` and `FieldName(association)` to match your need.